# CreateContainer Docker API volumes property does not make sense

Tags: docker, api, docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate

The Volumes property of the above API does not make sense to me.

Can anyone explain how to mount a host directory to a container path via the above api?

Answer (score 1):

That configuration is under:

```json
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
      "/host/path:/container/path"
    ]
  }
}
```

(using syntax like the `docker run -v` option); or, with a sufficiently new Docker API version (including the 1.37 you cite)

```json
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Mounts": [
      {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/host/path",
        "Target": "/container/path"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(like the `docker run --mount` option).

The `"Binds"` field also supports Docker named volumes with `volume-name:/container-path` syntax; in the `"Mounts"` field you'd specify `"Type": "volume"`.

The top-level `"Volumes"` field is for anonymous volumes.

(I'm not sure why there's not an anonymous-volume option in `"Mounts"`; otherwise you can sort of see the evolution of the API as first named volumes and then tmpfs mounts were eventually added in.  Also consider using a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) instead of directly programming the HTTP API.)